# UIPopoverController & UIImagePickerControl: "Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window"

Tags: ipad, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to display a UIImagePickerControl in my iPad app. At first, the debugger told me that I needed to put it in a popover when doing it on an iPad. So I wrote the following code:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 400.0) 
                         inView:self.view
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                       animated:YES];
```

However, now I get the following error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'`

Any suggestions on what I should do? I know that self.view **should** have a window, but apparently... it doesn't?

Comment: This is also probably the quickest chunk of code I've found to get a quick popover controller happening. Well done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can happen if that bit of code is getting executed before the view is loaded, as `self.view` is still nil and therefore so is `self.view.window`.

Is it possible that you're doing this in an init method or some other place before the view is loaded (before `-viewDidLoad:` is called)?

Comment: Good call--I moved the function call to `-viewDidAppear:` and it works properly now!

Answer (score 2):

This error had me baffled but it turned out that it was because the `barButtonItem` I was passing in to `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem` was a `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` item ant an actual button. My user error but just so people know this can als